# Problem combining animation actions

Tags: animation, .fbx, actions

I trying to combine two animations whitch was exported from blender in fbx format, but every time I try to do that the second action start in the "reset position" of the character and all the position changes ruining all the animations[image][image].

the second animation hand positions should like this[image]

Comment: without any "useful" information and without seeing any settings it is just guessing around. so please provide a blend file, so we can reproduce your problem. You can delete all "not necessary" stuff of your blend file before. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris I just add some images to the post. thank you!

Comment: could you please share your file (at least your armature): https://pasteall.org/blend/